# Is it possible to vary the subscription rates based on previous subscription in In-App Purchase iOS

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, ios13, swift5, in-app

I have two type of subscriptions, Monthly and Yearly and I set a price for that. How can I change the price of Yearly subscription for a user already have Monthly subscription.

Example:

User with out any subscription
Monthly price - $25
Yearly price - $79

User with Monthly subscription
Monthly price - $25
Yearly price - $54

I want to change price like this. Is this possible through In-App purchase auto renewable subscription in iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stack overflow!

You could achieve something like that with [subscription offers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/implementing_subscription_offers_in_your_app), but there is no need to do that.

The switch from one subscription to another doesn't necessarily happen immediately*, but at the next renewal date. So, if a user has a monthly subscription and switches during that to a yearly subscription, then the monthly will stay "active" till it expires and then the yearly subscription starts. So, after the yearly subscription expires, your user would have been subscribed for 13 months (one year plus one month).

*This doesn't apply when your subscriptions not only differ in duration but also in their service level. You can read more about `upgrade` and `downgrade` of subscriptions in the *Ranking Subscriptions Within the Group* section of this [article](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/subscriptions/) from Apple.

Comment: Thank you Paul, I have to clarify that, If the user have monthly subscription and then the user purchased an yearly subscription, that will automatically renewed to one year plus that remaining days of month right?

Comment: Yes and no. In the end it boils down to that, but technical the user finishes his monthly subscription and this renews to a yearly subscription.

Comment: Hi paul, i read about subscription offers. I think i can tackle this with subscription offers right? I have a doubt that if i give the offer once, is that offer expires? or can i give that offer later also?

Comment: Since you are determine the eligibility criteria besides the fact that a user has an active subscription, you can grant the offer whenever you want.

Comment: Thank you Paul, Thank you for your great support

Comment: I am happy I could help